# How can I share apps and music purchased on one apple ID between 7 devices?

Tags: itunes, drm, authorization

I have:

- 1 Macbook Pro for office use
- 1 Macbook Air for personal travel use
- 1 Mac Mini to run my home theater system
- 1 iMac that my wife and kids use
- 1 iPad v1 for the kids to play with
- 1 iPad v2 for myself
- 1 iPhone 3GS

I'm running into problems with iTunes telling me I've authorized too many devices. I have seen in some places people saying that I'm allowed to authorized up to 10 devices, 5 of which can be computers, but iTunes seems to be treating computers and other devices the same for me, limiting me to 5 no matter what.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: 10 devices can be authorized to play content. 5 of which can automatically download (so deselect that on devices that don't need it), 5 of which can be computers (so you can choose to reset all if you show as 5 computers instead of the 4 you have listed in case of an old machine still counting against the total. You can always call AppleCare or use ExpressLane since this is billing support and Apple has a direct interest in making sure you can still buy more apps and use the purchases you already made.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you have authorized Macs you no longer have.

Go to your account in iTunes, under Apple ID Overview you can see how many computers you have authorized and (once a year) you can deauthorize all, after that you should be able to reauthorize your Macs. (This does not affect iOS devices, as they do not count towards your 5 devices limit)

Comment: Thanks. I did that, and it seems to be working OK for now. I thought that maybe my other devices were counting towards the five, but apparently that's not the case.